# What keyboard signal apart from Ctrl-C can I catch?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a (C, Linux) application which handles Ctrl-C SIGINT by shutting down.
I'd like to add another signal handler so that I can use another keystroke combo for "reload configuration while running".

So I'm looking from a signal I can send to the foreground process by keystroke, which doesn't force the process to quit or suspend. Are there any others?

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6764265/371250

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ctrl+Z`,

```
SIGTSTP
```

Value = 20

For more details refer this [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can try `Ctrl - \` which is `SIGQUIT` if you absolutely need it to be a keystroke (you *can* catch it).

Answer (score 3):

Your program can use [`SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGUSR1_and_SIGUSR2) to do whatever it wants, but there's no single-stroke way of sending them like how a Ctrl+C sends a `SIGINT` signal.  You have to use something like [`kill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) to send the signal, e.g. `kill -USR1 <mypid>`.

Comment: Correct, so that's not what I want.

Comment: @blueshift But keep in mind that those are the signals you are _supposed_ to handle.  By changing the others you are creating unexpected behavior.  This is not necessarily bad unless you are distributing the program.

Comment: A fair point. But this is internal only, embedded system, not a problem.

Comment: It is a shame. SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are precisely the signals that we can handle better and would be very useful to have keyboard shortcuts for them.