# Catch CTRL +D in ksh

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

How can I catch the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard in `ksh` and after exit?

```
while true; do
  read cmd
  echo $cmd
  if [ "$cmd" = "?????" ]; then
        break
  fi

done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is "end-of-file (EOF)" and what you need to do is "trap" that input.  Unfortunately, there isn't a EOF character -- when you hit the chord <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, the tty sends a signal to the reading application that the input stream has finished by returning a sentinel value to make it exit.

To prevent this character from being treated as further input, it has to be an *special* character (e.g. something out of range like -1).  When the terminal detects such a character, it buffers all its characters so that the input is empty, which in turn makes your program read zero bytes (end of file).

You may be running into an issue because the `read` command exits when receiving `eof`, so your script was likely terminating before getting to your conditional.  This has the side effect of breaking out of the script, but likely not in the way you wanted.

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

# unmap so we can control the behavior
stty eof ^D

while true; do
  read cmd
  echo $cmd

  # are we out of input? let's get a taco
  if [ ! -n "$cmd" ]; then
    echo 'taco time'
  fi

done
```

When you get to other signals (like ^C) the general form is:

trap [commands] [signals to catch]

Comment: `[ ! -n "$cmd" ]` would not work when ENTER is pressed without inputting any chars.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `while read`:

```
while read cmd; do
  echo $cmd
done
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works. But how can i use a comparison?

Comment: Why do you have to use a comparison?

Comment: for personal Culture and increase my skills.
Maybe oneday i should need to do a break when i press ctrl + something

Comment: When EOF is seen, read gets nothing. CTRL-D is just used to indicate the EOF. It's not similar to other CTRL-something like CTRL-C which would usually send a signal.

Comment: For signals: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937743/what-keyboard-signal-apart-from-ctrl-c-can-i-catch), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764265/ctrl-c-sigint-ctrl-x), [link3](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html), for EOF: [link4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Comment: Even better, when read gets eof, the command exits with a non-zero status. This is exactly why `while read` works: when it hits eof, read exits non-zero, and the while loop can exit.